# how to get the keywords suggestions like youtube in php

Tags: php, json, youtube-api

In my project i want to display the youtube videos based upon the keywords entered in the text field, But when i am entering text in the text field the keywords suggestions which are coming in youtube, not appearing in the bottom of my text field.

Can any one tell me how to get the keywords suggestion like youtube when we enter any keywords in the text field like in the below image using youtube data api.

[image]

Comment: Look here for a start: http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/

Comment: are the keywords that you want to appear on your end, or do you mean you want to get the keywords from youtube?

Comment: yes, i want to get keywords from youtube@hexblot

Comment: i got the different results when used the below link
http://shreyaschand.com/blog/2013/01/03/google-autocomplete-api/

Answer (score 0):

In jQueryUI there is autocomplete widget http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/
You can do anything you want using it

Answer (score 0):

You can build this type of functionality by using the javascript. jQuery Autocomplete is the best example to build this type of funcitonality. You can refer http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/‎ link